# Angularjs Control the expand and collapse of an acordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to understand how works the ui.bootstrap accordion in angularjs. In my case of use, I have three accordions of which only the first is allowed to open. The rest of them should not open when the user click on their header until an option is selected from the previous accordion.

Now, I am experimenting with a controller which shows a error message when the user click on the second and third accordeon and, after that, it close them. This is my Plunker with my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rSg6Az?p=preview

The part of the error message works fine but I can not get that the accordeon selected is closed when I click it.

Any idea?

Regards:

Adrian Ferreres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I give you the thanks for your answer and my apologies for my delay to answer it. I didn't tested your solutions because I found two solutions which I like more than you told me. The first was given by Vanya Dineva in the official mail group of Angular:

> Here's a couple of things you can try:
>
> 1. Notice the accordionGroup directive uses the collapse directive in its template (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion->group.html )
>      You can modify and instead of having collapse="!isOpen" you can replace the isOpen with a new variable that you would set to false until your condition is met
> 2. Notice the ng-click="toggleOpen()" in the accordion group template (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion-group.html ). Try creating a custom function e.g. ng-click="openIfConditionMet()" and put your logic inside the function

The second was found by myself. I add a modal window to show the error message when a user tries to open an accordion. In the function which closes the window I put the code to close the accordion:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rSg6Az?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass), and bind it to the value of the option in each previous accordion.

Answer (score 0):

You can probaly warp your assignment to a `$timeout` but there is already in master the support for `is-disabled`. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/9c43ae7c0a66ff454c97296122d8f82c89ac4d5e

You can either build it your self or wait for the next release :-)